The import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.cache cannot be resolved
I am trying to use the  import  org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.cache.CacheConfig in order to
CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom().setMaxCacheEntries(cacheMaxEntries != null ? cacheMaxEntries : DEFAULT_CACHE_MAX_ENTRIES).setMaxObjectSize(cacheMaxObjectSize != null ? cacheMaxObjectSize : DEFAULT_CACHE_MAX_OBJECT_SIZE).setSharedCache(false).build();

But it appears that it can not be recognized even though I have also used these other imputs successfully
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;

I am only having issue with the CacheConfig
Even trying to use the  org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl implementation
And I am also using these dependencies
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.14</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

Help please :c
It should recognize the CacheConfig the same as the other imports...

Why the project has dependencies for different versions of the same library?

You missed to add the right dependency for your version of the Apache HTTP client 5 cache library:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient5-cache</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>

